Read JSON array as enums with type based on property
My JSON input is this:
{
  // other fields
  "context": [
    {
      "id": "age",
      "name": "Age",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "730 days +"
    },
    {
      "id": "v2Score",
      "name": "V2 Score",
      "type": "number",
      "value": 5.9
    },
    {
      "id": "maturity",
      "name": "Maturity",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "High"
    },
    {
      "id": "coverage",
      "name": "Product Coverage",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Low"
    },
    {
      "id": "threat_intensity",
      "name": "Threat Intensity",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Very Low"
    },
    {
      "id": "threat_recency",
      "name": "Threat Recency",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "No recorded events"
    },
    {
      "id": "threat_sources",
      "name": "Threat Sources",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "No recorded events"
    }
  ]
}

and my Context POJO class looks like this
class Context {
  private final Age age;
  private final Maturity maturity;
  private final Coverage coverage;
  private final ThreatIntensity threatIntensity;
  private final ThreatRecency threatRecency;
  
  // constructor, getters
}

All of the above fields in Context are enums. Using Age as an example:
enum Age {
  @JsonProperty("0 - 7 days")
  LESS_THAN_ONE_WEEK,
  @JsonProperty("7 - 30 days")
  ONE_WEEK_TO_ONE_MONTH,
  @JsonProperty("30 - 365 days")
  ONE_MONTH_TO_ONE_YEAR, 
  @JsonProperty("365 - 730 days")
  ONE_TO_TWO_YEARS, 
  @JsonProperty("730 days + ")
  MORE_THAN_TWO_YEARS
}

the object in the array with "id": "age" corresponds to the Age enum type, and "value": "730 days +" corresponds to Age.MORE_THAN_TWO_YEARS.
How can I deserialize this array of objects into individual enums? Each object in the array corresponds to exactly one type of enum (i.e., there will never be two objects in the array with the same id), but the objects in the array are not guaranteed to be in the same order every time. Is there a way to do this with annotations, such as @JsonTypeInfo? Additionally, while I don't expect any of the enums to be missing, I'd like to be able to pass "missing" enums as null. For example, if the object with "id": "maturity" was not present in the array, the associated Maturity enum object should be deserialized as null. So far data returned from this API has either included all or none of these elements (resulting in "context": []), although I have no guarantee that's true everywhere.
I can also ignore any objects in the array with an id that I don't care about (in this case, v2Score and threat_sources). I included them in the example to demonstrate that there may be data outside of what I want that should be ignored. Additionally, the "name" and "type" fields in each of the objects can be ignored, as only the id is needed to determine the enum type, and only "value" is needed to select which enum of that type.
I got about as far as this before getting stuck on what to do. I'm doing my best to avoid making switch statements over the id or value fields, as additions in the future would likely cause bugs.
@JsonCreator
Context(
  @JsonProperty("age") Age age,
  @JsonProperty("Maturity") Maturity maturity,
  @JsonProperty("coverage") Coverage coverage,
  @JsonProperty("threat_intensity") ThreatIntensity intensity,
  @JsonProperty("threat_recency") ThreatRecency recency,
) {
  // basic constructor
}

For the above input, the following object should be created:
context.getAge() // Age.MORE_THAN_TWO_YEARS
context.getMaturity() // Maturity.HIGH
context.getCoverage() // Coverage.LOW
context.getThreatIntensity() // ThreatIntensity.VERY_LOW
context.getThreatRecency() // ThreatRecency.NONE

Not all of the elements in the input array are (logically) enums, but all of the elements that I care about are enums.
I'm guessing I need to use @JsonTypeInfo on each of the constructor arguments in some way? From what I know of how it works, if I was able to annotate Enum like this, it would deserialize the individual enums correctly. I'm not sure how to translate the array into individual parameters though.
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
  as = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
  property = "id",
  defaultImpl = Void.class,
  visible = false)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value=Age.class, name="age"),
  @Type(value=Maturity.class, name="maturity")
  @Type(value=Coverage.class, name="coverage")
  @Type(value=ThreatIntensity.class, name="threat_intensity")
  @Type(value=ThreatRecency.class, name="threat_recency")})
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {

  // annotating the implicitly-declared valueOf(String) method for Enums
  @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static abstract <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(@JsonProperty("value") String name);
}

I do also know how to make a custom deserializer for this, but doing so makes the code much more brittle, especially if it's extended or changed in the future.

Are ALL the elements in the array Enums?  V2 Score seems different and you don't list it next to Age.  If so, I don't think you'll achieve this declaratively with @JsonTypeInfo etc, but you'll need to write your own Serializer/Deserializer then it'll be quite simple.

Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Added additional information for your questions

don't put "edit" sections in your question - those are for answers that go out of date and require an actual separate edit section to clarify what changed since the time of posting. Just work the requested missing details into your post so that to anyone finding your question, it reads like any other.

It might be me, but this question is still quite unclear. I don't understand how an element with the fields id, name, type and value should be deserialized into a POJO Context with completely different fields. Do you need to convert the whole JSON array into a single Context or array of Context? The Context class doesn't even completely correspond to the one "example" with the getter invocations. Furthermore, you keep referring to v2Score and threat_sources as "elements", those are values. Do you mean that you don't need some fields when they possess certain values?

reworked the question again with more detailed examples, hopefully it's clear this time around.

@EarthTurtle thank you for expanding your question and adding the snippet with the JsonTypeInfo. That last part was quite important in my opinion for the question. However, I believe that what you want to achieve cannot be done with just annotations as you're trying to convert an array of values to an object with some of those fields mapping specific enum values. This seems to be such a specific case that I don't think a combination of annotations could help you with it (I hope to be wrong).

@dani-vta I appreciate it. Did one last look around, it appears that what I'm asking might not be possible with java enums https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2739

It looks like the above link confirms that this question does not have a solution. Is it acceptable to write and accept my own answer stating as much? Just so that anyone in the future knows its a dead end.

@EarthTurtle yes, it is.

I've confirmed that what I am attempting is not possible, as java does not provide the means to deserialize to "any generic enum" https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2739
